# How to move all digits in a string to the beginning of the string?

Tags: java, regex, string

For the following string:

```
String str="asd14sd67fgh007";
```

I want output like:

```
1467007asdsdfgh
```

I know how to split a string, but I don't know how to get this. For split, I have this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str="asd14sd67fgh007";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+([0-9]+)\\w+([0-9]+)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        matcher.find();
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to not use a regex for this? Just scan through the characters and divide them into 2 separate `StringBuilders`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

2 `replaceAll()` can do it  (If you really want to use regex :P):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s= "asd14sd67fgh007";
        String correctedString = s.replaceAll("\\D+", "") + s.replaceAll("\\d+", "");
        System.out.println(correctedString);
}
```

O/P :

```
1467007asdsdfgh
```

Note :

> `"\\D+"` ==> replace all *non-numeric* characters with `""`. (will
>   give you all numbers).
>
> `"\\d+"` ==> replace all digits with `""` (will
>   give you all non-numeric characters)

Comment: @Chanakya - Ywc. But this one will be slower than other approaches :)

Comment: Well, I meant more like the code will be less clear, but I guess you can add those as comments and name the method properly ;)

Answer (score 16):

Here's a simple solution using `char[]`s and `StringBuilder`s:

```
String input = "asd14sd67fgh007";
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
// temporary, for storing alphabetic characters
StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
// iterating input's characters one by one
for (char c: input.toCharArray()) {
    // digits, go to output in their order
    if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
        output.append(c);
    }
    // letters, go to temporary to be appended later
    else if (Character.isAlphabetic(c)){
        temp.append(c);
    }
    // punctuation gets lost
}
// appending temporary alphabetics to digits and printing
System.out.println(output.append(temp));
```

**Output**

```
1467007asdsdfgh
```

Comment: ah didn't think about the `#isDigit`. nice.

Comment: @gonzo yeah `Character` has some very handy utility methods.

Comment: This will probably be the fastest solution :P +1

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar has a clever way as well that I would have never thought of.

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar yeah you got nice one too :)

Comment: @Mena - Ya. but only slower :P

Comment: Important to note that [`isDigit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit-char-) will also many other Unicode digit ranges in addition to `'0'`-`'9'` (`ISO-LATIN-1`).

Answer (score 9):

You can do something like this. Use `StringBuilder` to keep track of the front and back while looping through all the `char`s.

```
String str="asd14sd67fgh007";
StringBuilder front = new StringBuilder(str.length());
StringBuilder back = new StringBuilder(str.length());
for (char c : str.toCharArray()){
    if (c>=48 && c<=57){ //If numeric
        front.append(c);
    }else{
        back.append(c);
    }
}
front.append(back.toString());
System.out.println(front.toString());
```

Output

```
1467007asdsdfgh
```

Comment: Hmm. Looks like this one is faster than Mena's :)

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar wonder if it is because the code is checking 2 conditions instead of 1? Mena could change the `else if` to an `else` assuming the input string is alpha-numeric.

Comment: And `Character.isDigit()` actually does about 4 to 5 internal calls to return true or false. `isAlphabetic()` isn't trivial either.

Comment: IT would also probablly be a good idea to set the size of your stringbuilders to the length of the input string thereby avoiding any reallocations.

Comment: @plugwash thanks for the advice. I have updated my solution to reflect this. :)

Answer (score 0):

If it is not mandatory to use regular expression, you can just use a loop to achieve the output:

```
    String str = "asd14sd67fgh007";
    String digits = "", characters = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
        if (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))) {
            digits += str.charAt(i);
        } else {
            characters += str.charAt(i);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Result is :" + digits + characters);
```

Comment: Building a string every time could get expensive depending how big the input `String` is. I would suggest using `StringBuilder`.